# Photosynthetic efficiency and light harvesting efficiency

Tags: biophysics, photosynthesis

Is there some sort of measure of the light harvesting efficiency (possibly like transfer time) that is directly related to the photosynthetic efficiency in some sort of equation? Also, how important is light harvesting efficiency to photosynthetic efficiency?